# Stopping ajax code from running based on result from database

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a bootbox dialog with a button named save in a view called `table_data.php` and I would like to determine whether the Ajax post to database will be done based on a result obtained from the database.

I want the data only to be saved when the database query in `home_model.php` does not return any rows. However, when I do it, it does not work. It is a cms and I am using codeigniter framework.

My page is blank. And nothing appears. Please help me. I am new to web and have very little experience with JavaScript and php and just started on ajax. Your help will be much appreciated.

table_data.php (view)

```
 bootbox.dialog({
      message: '<div class="row">  ' +
               '<div class="col-md-12"> ' +
               '<form class="form-horizontal"> ' +
               '<div class="form-group"> ' +
               '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="awesomeness">Table ID: </label> ' +
               '<div class="col-md-4">' +
               '<input id="idtable" type="text" value="'+table_column_15+'"/>' +
               '</div><br>' +
               '</div>'+
               '</form> </div>  </div>',
      title: "Form",
      buttons: {
        success: {
          label: "Save",
          className: "btn-success",
          callback: function() {
                                console.log('save');
                                console.log($('#re_confirm')[0].checked);
                                var valueid = document.getElementById('idtable').value
                                if(valueid == 0)
                                  myFunction();
                                var valueid2 = document.getElementById('idtable').value
                                if(valueid2==0)
                                  return;

                                 $.ajax({
                                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/home/check_occupied",
                                    type: "post", // To protect sensitive data
                                    data: {
                                            "table_id" : valueid2
                                            "session_id" : table_column_15
                                        //and any other variables you want to pass via POST
                                          },
                                    success:function(response){
                                    // Handle the response object
                                       console.log(response);
                                       var check = $(response);
                                     }
                                  });

                                   if(check==0)
                                    return;

                                   $.ajax({
                                   url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/home/update_booking",
                                   type: "post",
                                   data: {
                                       "table_id" : $('#idtable').val(),
                                   },
                                   success: function(response){
                                       ...
                                   }
                               });
          }
        },
        ...
        ,
        ...
      }
    });
```

home_model.php (model)

```
  public function check_occupied($tableid,$sessionid)
        {

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE table_id=$tableid and session=$sessionid;
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);

            if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
                $imp = 1;
            else
                $imp = 0;

            return $imp;
        }
```

home.php(controller)

```
public function check_occupied()
    {

        $tableid = $_POST['table_id'];
        $sessionid = $_POST['session_id'];
        $imp = $this->home_model->check_occupied($tableid,$sessionid);

        $this->load->view('table_data', $imp);
    }
```

Comment: Syntax error on `$sql = "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE table_id=$tableid and session=$sessionid";` forget to close double quotes

Comment: but it still doesn't work - seems the problem is coming from table_data.php(the view)

Comment: What problem??have you check you console??

Comment: $.ajax({  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/home/check_occupied", type: "post",data: { "table_id" : valueid2  "session_id" : table_column_15
 },   success:function(response){ console.log(response);
 var check = $(response);
 }
  });

Comment: the problem is there it seems

Comment: now i cannot open the bootbox dialog

Comment: Thanks Saty  - trying to help me

Comment: remove `return` above ajax call because after return type you code is vanish

Comment: Hi Saty, the bootbox can open - but the checking does not work - i don't want to send data to database when there are rows returned from the database in the check_occupied function in home_model

Comment: by  the way, i didn't remove the return statement - it was the matter of missing commas

Comment: In the $.ajax jquery config you can have an `error: function() {}`, if you do this then tell '/home/check_occupied' to return a status code of 409 (http://goo.gl/keU7fl). It will mean when it fails it goes into the error function instead of the success. In the check occupied method add an if that checks the $imp value and if its is 0 call `$this->output->set_status_header(409, 'duplicate booking found');` else `$this->load->view(...)`.

Comment: @orangepill this is a trial

Answer (score 0):

I found a few syntax minor errors but the biggest problem is where you are attempting to use the var `check` as in `if(check==0)`.

Your condition evaluation `if(check==0)` is outside the success function of the ajax call to check_occupied. Therefore, `if(check==0)` will execute before the success function runs and sets a value for `check`. If you `console.log(check);` just before the `if` statement you will find the value to be 'undefined'. This console result will also be logged before the output of `console.log(response);' which will confirm the order of execution.

In other words, you need to decide on whether to run the next ajax call inside of the success function of the check_occupied ajax call.

Here's my version. It's untested but I think the concept is sound. This shows only the `callback:` for the "Save" button.

```
callback: function () {
  console.log('save');
  console.log($('#re_confirm')[0].checked);
  var valueid = document.getElementById('idtable').value;
  if (valueid === 0) {
    myFunction();
  }
  var valueid2 = document.getElementById('idtable').value;
  if (valueid2 === 0) {
    return;
  }
  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/home/check_occupied",
    type: "post", // To protect sensitive data
    data: {
      "table_id": valueid2,
      //??? where is table_column_15 declared and initialized? Some global var?
      "session_id": table_column_15
        //and any other variables you want to pass via POST
    },
    success: function (response) {
      // Handle the response object
      console.log('response='+response);
      //if I read check_occupied() right, response should only be 1 or 0 
      //there is no need to assign it to another var, eg. var check = response
      //there is no apparent need to turn it into a JQuery object with $(response) either
      if (response > 0) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/home/update_booking",
          type: "post",
          data: {
            "table_id": $('#idtable').val()
          },
          success: function (response) {
          }
        });
      }
    }//end of success function callback for check_occupied() ajax
    console.log('ajax to check_occupied is done.');
  });
}
```